# Symbolic Integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

I am just trying to solve an equation in matlab but it does give me a warning.
**"Warning Explicit integral could not be found"**
After some search people suggested to wrap my equation with Double() method but even with that I recieve wrong answer( ans=0)  which I calculated on mathematica/maple as 4.62240566.

[image: this is my equation]

I think its something related with floating point but I am not exactly sure how to fix it

```
syms t
int( (t^2+100)^(-1/2)*exp(-10^-3*(t^2 + 100)^(1/2)),t , 1, Inf) 
   Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from this http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/int.html the code you would need is:

```
int(1/(exp(1000*(t^2 + 100)^(1/2))*(t^2 + 100)^(1/2)), t , 1,Inf)
```

Or perhaps you can use

```
t == 1..inf
```

And wrap it with `vpa` like in the example, rather than with `double`.